# what does "lost a shilling and found a penny" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am translating a British story and I came across this expression

"you look like you lost a shilling and found a penny". I am not sure I understand what it means.

Comment: You could help us interpret this better by giving supplying more of the context where you found the expression. Conceivably, it could be referring to a coin collector who lost a shilling but found a penny, but I suspect the meaning is more metaphorical. It might be another way of taking about a [silver lining](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/silver-lining), but, without more context, it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 10):

A [shilling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling) and a [penny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny) are two increments of currency, where a shilling is made up of 12 pennies. As it happens, [the shilling is no longer in use in Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling_%28British_coin%29#Withdrawal), so this is somewhat of an archaic saying.

Essentially though, the saying implies that you've found something less valuable than what you lost — or simply, that you look disappointed about something.

A more modern version of the saying might go: "you look like you've lost a dollar and found a penny".

Comment: While the found article may be less desirable, I think the meaning is more about the *value* of the lost and found articles.

Comment: One shilling was worth 12 (old) pence.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to 'decimalisation' in February 1971, British currency followed the structure that had been [used since pre-800 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling#Anglo-Saxon). This was as follows:

> One *pound* (*£1*) = 20 *shillings* (denoted thus: *20s* or *20/-*)
>   One *shilling* (*1/-*) = 12 *pence* (*12d*) (singular *penny*) (the abbreviation *d* for *penny/pence* originated from the Roman *[denarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denarius)*)
>   Thus there were 240 *pence* to the *pound* (strictly the *pound sterling*, so named because the value of the *pound* was originally equivalent to the value of one pound weight of sterling silver).
>
> The *penny* was further subdivided into:
>   - 2 *half-pennies* (*½d*) (pronounced *ha'penny* (singular) or *ha'pence* (plural)); or
>   - 4 *farthings* (*¼d*)
>
> Coins with values of *one-quarter of a farthing* (1/960th of £1) and *one-third of a farthing* were in use in some of the British colonies in the 19th century.

On decimalisation in 1971, the value of the *pound* was retained unchanged, but became subdivided into 100 *new pence* (abbreviation *p*) (the *new* has since been dropped).

The name *shilling* was dropped, but the then *one shilling* coin became worth *5 new pence*. All pre-decimalisation coins of value *sixpence* (half *shilling*) or higher simply adopted their corresponding new values, and pre-decimalisation coins of lower value (which had no exact post-decimalisation equivalent) were withdraw and replaced by 'copper' coins of value *½p* (since dropped), *1p* & *2p* (still in use, although coin size has changed).

So back to the original question:

> *to lose a shilling and find a penny*

refers to the pre-decimalisation *one-shilling* and *one-penny* coins, and (as others have intimated) was an old British idiom indicating that you had lost something of value and found something of considerably lower value.

The pre-decimalisation shilling coins [remained in use until 1991](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling_%28British_coin%29#Withdrawal), but their new equivalent, a smaller five-(new)pence coin, continues in use. Sadly, the old one-penny coin is long deceased.

---

Finally, clarification of plural of *penny* (supplementing the answer from @Hannele):

> The usual plural of *penny* - used when referring to it as a currency unit - is ***pence***.
>   All British coins with values **between** 1p (one penny) and £1 (one pound) use the word *pence* in stating their value.
>
> Another form of the plural is ***pennies***, but this is normally used only when referring to multiples of one-penny coins: *I have three pennies* would be understood as meaning *I have three one-penny coins*.

Comment: Another symbol for the pound, besides the '£' symbol currently in usage, is a simple capital 'L' (standing for *librum*, meaning pound as in the weight, and indeed the '£' is simply an ornate capital 'L' with a bar across it).

Comment: I've never seen a simple *L* used for the pound - where is that in use? I agree that the *£* symbol is an ornate *L*.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd), and I'm sure I've seen it that way in old books. I thought I'd seen lowercase 'l' too, but Googling suggests that's unlikely.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions it once (in the opening line), but gives no reference to support it and anyone could have written that. You may have "seen it that way in ***old*** books" (and I don't dispute that it may have been used in the past), but your previous comment (as I understood it) suggests that ***L*** is still used.

Comment: Ah; I meant that 'L' was used as a symbol for the pound in the pre-decimal system, along with 's' and 'd' for shillings and pence. I can't edit the comment, but apologies for the confusion. As I said above '£' is the only symbol currently in usage (obviously excluding typographical variants, and terms like 'GBP').

Comment: Ah, my apologies for the misinformation - I'm Canadian, and we only use *penny* to refer to the coin - *cent* is used to refer to the unit of currency. I'd wrongfully assumed it was archaic, and have updated my answer. It is useful to have a clear notion of the difference!

Comment: By the way, it would be better on the Stack Exchange to leave a comment on my answer, rather than appending it to yours - it was only happenstance that brought me back to this page to see yours.

Comment: Can you give more on the meaning of the proverb? Is there an Aesop's Fable to go along?

Comment: @Hannele Tx for comments. Apologies. I did start doing a comment on your answer but then decided to do a fuller answer. I had thought I had left a comment on your answer mentioning the update in mine. Sorry if I didn't. Will now update mine to reflect the update to yours.

Comment: @Mitch Not without researching it myself I'm afraid.

Comment: @TrevorD: but that's what the OP is asking about. Are you saying you'd have to do research to answer the question that you've purported to answer?

Comment: The question was *What does it mean?* - and that I have answered. I've explained the meaning of the *shilling* & *penny* and stated that "[the idiom] was an old British idiom indicating that you had lost something of value and found something of considerably lower value." More than that I would have to research.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old fashioned but not obsolete saying for that means you look like something sad happened to you. It would be said in a light hearted way in my area of the North of England. Eg. "Eh lass, what's to do wi you? You look like you've dropped a shill in' and found ha'penny!" (half a penny). It would be meant to lift you out of your gloom by making a joke of your expression. Shillings haven't been in use since decimalisation but old sayings persist amongst older people.

Answer (score -1):

The L is from Latin Libra abbreviated to Lb, or a pound. At some time in history it may have indicated a pound in weight of sterling silver. The expression is still heard in the Spanish and Portuguese *Libras Esterlinas*

The original expression referred to, lost a shilling and found a penny is more commonly reduced by dialect to something more colloquial, like *lost ten bob and found a tanner* which is alliterative and has a meter.

Ten bob was a ten shilling (50p today) banknote, a significant amount. A tanner was a sixpence coin, or half a shilling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).