# Seeking a history of q

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

Reading some older texts recently, I came across

> L.--    s.--    d.--    q.

which were obviously [Old Money](http://projectbritain.com/moneyold.htm) accounting abbreviations.
For whatever reason, I  had never seen *q.* before, or had not remembered that I had.

The matter of [L.s.d.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383647/what-does-l-s-d-stand-for) has been questioned and answered here, so I will not bother with that now. I did not find it simple to confirm that *q.* stood for *farthings* as the abbreviation does not seem to have ever been common, and certainly would have little use now.
I had help [from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_American_currency#/media/File:US-Colonial_(RI-282)-Rhode_Island-2_Jul_1780_OBV.jpg) [image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_American_currency#/media/File:US-Colonial_(RI-282)-Rhode_Island-2_Jul_1780_OBV.jpg]

making things clear what *q.* probably meant.  Searching *farthing* produced [quadrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrans). and the *q.* became obvious. The Greek form of *quadrans* is rendered *farthing* in the [KJV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version).
I have only found appearances of *q.* in 18th Century works, and only involving currency exchange.

My question is when did *q* become an abbreviation for *farthing* and was it ever a common abbreviation. I've reached the end of trails on this. I hope someone else can help.

Comment: I'm more worried about the apparent interchangeability of ſ and f in the picture. I mean, the first f in "pofſeſſor" is clearly an f rather than an ſ.

Comment: The OED isn’t any help. It is listed under Latin abbreviations of q as “quadrans, farthing Obs” (obsolete), but with no dated illustration of usage. (Not surprisingly as it is not a word and the OED doesn‘t quote ledger books and the like.) btw. I would change your title to indicate the context in which you wish the history (as an abbreviation for farthing) and there is no need to capitalize ‘history’ unless you are going capitalize all nouns, which would be a little unfair on little q, which is the subject of your question.

Comment: @MrLister — It looks to me as if it is the double ff ligature. Presumably the printers didn't have the double-ſ  ligature or picked the wrong one up by mistake. But why are you worried about it? Seems a good question to me, who was around when farthings were still in use (although not farthingales).

Comment: @ David  Yes, i thought it unfair to "q" not to use a cap, , but q. was causing me problems. Well, I edited.

Comment: @J.Taylor - you are essentially asking for earliest usage of q for quadrans (farthings) , correct?

Comment: @MrLister: It doesn't look like an "ff" to me. The ſ symbol fairly often has a line sticking out of it on the left side at the height of the crossbar on 'f". They can still be distinguished because in "ſ" the line doesn't continue to the right side of the letter

Comment: @user159691 yes, earliest usage, if it can be established, is a major solution.

Comment: According to this site https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/manuscriptsandspecialcollections/researchguidance/weightsandmeasures/money.aspx  -  ***Farthings were abbreviated to 'qua'**, short for 'quandrans', or a quarter of a penny. The word 'farthing' is an old English word meaning 'a fourth-thing'.*

Comment: @user159691 thanks for noting that. I ran into several abbreviations beyond :"q."  for farthing.  there are several mysteries in my mind about all this, including whether farthing began as a 4 way cut of the  A-S  penny, or as a separate coin.

Comment: Why would a farthing be used in America? ie in Rhode Island and Providence? And what is a 'Spanish milled DOLLAR'? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colony_of_Rhode_Island_and_Providence_Plantations

Comment: @ Jelila        This was the Spanish 8 Real silver coin , htps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dollar   The RR&PP note pictured was produced under an Act of 1780,  during the American Revolution.

Comment: @Jelila   For some time after the Revolution, British  money still circulated freely in the US, as it had been the only legal currency for over 250 years. Before Federal coinage began, the Spanish dollar was often valued against the Pound Sterling.

Comment: Oh really? Thanks, how interesting, I had no idea! It makes sense - I'd never heard of it! ️

Comment: @Jelila  I'm glad you seem satisfied about the money issue

Comment: Ha ha that makes me smile...

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, q. Or qua. was used as an abbreviation for 'farthing' or 'quadrantes' in Latin (a quarter of a penny).

Ths [link](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=4LsztHwoQx0C&pg=PR23&lpg=PR23&dq=first%20occurrence%20of%20'qua'%20as%20abbreviation%20for%20farthing&source=bl&ots=_adw2DpR7T&sig=yv2os6w0F_OLoPCh1U7XPonwiBw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqwIHMprbZAhUHULwKHQgIDuEQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) mentions q. and qua. being used 'in the first half of the thirteenth century'.

Another coin known as a Quadrin or Mite is also a farthing or quarter-penny, Spanish, apparently:

From *An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*, 1731

> [Quadrin](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=a_tIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP698&lpg=PP698&dq=#v=onepage&q&f=false):
>   QUADRIN, a Mite, a small piece of Money in Value about a Farthing.

From *Dictionarium Britannicum* edited by Nathaniel Bailey, dated 1730

> [Mite](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=CoRZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP602&lpg=PP602&dq=#v=onepage&q&f=false):
>   Quadrin, a Mite, a small Piece of Money in Value about a farthing.

Comment: My answer is not illegible! You don't need to read the links, only click on them. I will have a go at embedding them.